# Save timer after exit and load it

Tags: python, windows

Hi i create my app in Python. I use customtkinter and i start to create timer but i to face a problem. I want to do when user exit from app then the timer time was saved to a file and when the program was opened, the timer appeared again only at the place where it stopped. And timer must be appeared after that user will print key from programm only then timer was appeared

This is my code

```
from customtkinter import *
from random import choice, uniform
import time
import atexit
import json

font = ("Comic Sans MS", 20)
storage_filename = "data.json"
key_filename = "user_key.txt"  # Add this line
timer_interval = 1000  # Интервал в миллисекундах (1 секунда)

def save_data(data):
    with open(storage_filename, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

def load_data():
    try:
        with open(storage_filename, 'r') as file:
            return json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}

@atexit.register
def save_on_exit():
    save_data({
        'last_run_time': time.time(),
        'user_key': access_key_entry.get()
    })

def generate_coefficient():
    if choice([True, False]):
        coefficient = uniform(1, 5)
        coefficient_label.configure(text=f"Коэффициент: {coefficient:.2f}x", text_color="orange", font=font)
    else:
        coefficient_label.configure(text="Пропуск", text_color="red")

    start_button.configure(state=NORMAL)
    start_timer()

def save_last_run_time():
    with open(storage_filename, 'w') as storage:
        storage.write(str(time.time()))

def get_last_run_time():
    try:
        with open(storage_filename, 'r') as storage:
            return float(storage.read().strip())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 0

def start_timer():
    root.after(timer_interval, update_timer)

def update_timer():
    global start_time
    elapsed_time = int(time.time() - start_time)
    if elapsed_time >= 0 and elapsed_time <= 2 * 60 * 60:
        hours, remainder = divmod(2 * 60 * 60 - elapsed_time, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        timer_label.configure(text=f"Осталось: {hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}")
        save_last_run_time()
        root.after(timer_interval, update_timer)
    else:
        timer_label.configure(text="Время вышло! Введите новый ключ.")
        access_key_label.pack()
        access_key_entry.pack()
        access_key_button.pack(pady=10)
        start_button.configure(state=DISABLED)

def ask_for_new_key():
    start_button.configure(state=NORMAL)
    access_key_label.pack()
    access_key_entry.pack()
    access_key_button.pack(pady=10)

    access_key_display.configure(text="", text_color="black")

    start_button.configure(command=check_access_key)

def check_access_key():
    global start_time
    entered_key = access_key_entry.get()
    saved_key = get_saved_access_key()

    if entered_key in user_keys:
        access_key_label.pack_forget()
        access_key_entry.pack_forget()
        access_key_button.pack_forget()
        start_button.pack(anchor="s")
        start_button.configure(command=generate_coefficient, state=NORMAL)
        access_key_display.configure(text=f"Ключ: {entered_key}", text_color="yellow")
        save_access_key(entered_key)

        last_run_time = get_last_run_time()
        elapsed_time = int(time.time() - last_run_time)
        if elapsed_time >= 0 and elapsed_time <= 2 * 60 * 60:
            start_time = last_run_time
            start_timer()
    elif entered_key == saved_key:
        access_key_label.pack_forget()
        access_key_entry.pack_forget()
        access_key_button.pack_forget()
        start_button.pack(anchor="s")
        start_button.configure(command=generate_coefficient, state=NORMAL)
        access_key_display.configure(text=f"Ключ: {entered_key}", text_color="yellow")
        last_run_time = get_last_run_time()
        elapsed_time = int(time.time() - last_run_time)
        if elapsed_time >= 0 and elapsed_time <= 2 * 60 * 60:
            start_time = last_run_time
            start_timer()
    else:
        access_key_display.configure(text="Доступ запрещен", text_color="red")

def save_access_key(entered_key):
    with open(key_filename, 'w') as key_file:
        key_file.write(entered_key)

def get_saved_access_key():
    try:
        with open(key_filename, 'r') as key_file:
            return key_file.read().strip()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None

user_keys = {"f3002b5a81967e98a5af9501cff6d860": "user", "OHQOgdSB0z28CyCk1JBH": "user",
             "popa": "user"}  # Замените на свои значения

root = CTk()
icon_path = "./djo.ico"
root.iconbitmap(icon_path)
root.title("LUCKY JET | HACK")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('350x300')

coefficient_label = CTkLabel(root, text="Нажмите кнопку 'Старт' для получения коэффициента")
coefficient_label.pack(pady=10)

access_key_label = CTkLabel(root, text="Введите ключ доступа:")
access_key_label.pack()

access_key_entry = CTkEntry(root)
access_key_entry.pack()

access_key_button = CTkButton(root, text="Ввести ключ", command=check_access_key)
access_key_button.pack(pady=10)

access_key_display = CTkLabel(root, text="", anchor="e")
access_key_display.pack(side="top", anchor="ce", padx=10, pady=10)

start_button = CTkButton(root, text="Старт", state=DISABLED)
start_button.pack(anchor="s")

timer_label = CTkLabel(root, text="", font=font)
timer_label.pack()

last_run_time = get_last_run_time()
elapsed_time = int(time.time() - last_run_time)

if elapsed_time >= 0 and elapsed_time <= 2 * 60 * 60:
    ask_for_new_key()
else:
    start_button.configure(state=NORMAL, command=generate_coefficient)
    start_time = last_run_time
    start_timer()

root.mainloop()
```

Almost everything worked out except this

Comment: You're new to programming, so here's a basic tip. For problems like this, write a small program that does only the very minimum. E.g. a program that *only* saves the timer. Another program that *only* loads the timer. This is a lot easier. And if one of those would still fail, ask us about those. See also [mcve]